# Difference between winforms,WPF and metro?

Tags: wpf, winforms, windows-8, windows-store-apps, windows-10-universal

How is Metro different from WPF and WinForms?

Are only metro style apps allowed to be sold on the Windows App Store?

Comment: __If__ you want to sell through the store then you need to learn/use Metro, yes. Otherwise you have many choices.

Answer (score 14):

Metro Apps are applications that are specifically written for Windows 8 using all the advantages that Windows 8 has to offer. They can be put on the Windows 8 app store. http://devcomponents.com/blog/?p=1061

WinForms is the old Windows format that was somewhat replaced by WPF. WPF is much more optimized and contains for example vector graphics. WPF provides much better performance when compared to WinForms applications. It provides a much richer UI experience. It uses XAML for development purposes (XML description of your UI). WinForms and WPF give you the existing Windows Look & Feel.

Metro Apps look much more like Windows Phone 7 applications but with much more functionality (but I think in the future both will converge). They are mainly addressed for the tablet market and touch screens (and hybrid devices in the future). Metro apps can be compared to IPad apps but much richer and with the full power of the Windows operation system.

If you want to write standard Windows applications that use a mouse interface and that work like current Windows application I recommend using WPF.

If you want to specifically address the Windows 8 market and create applications that are touch friendly you have to use Metro application.

I would not recommend using WinForms for new projects anymore. Only for old existing projects where the migration to WPF is too expensive in time and money.

You can look into this architecture guide published by MS patterns & practices for WPF and WinForms architectures for further advice (it doesn't contain Metro Apps yet). http://apparchguide.codeplex.com/

Hope that helps.

Comment: Ok so another lame question. To learn metro style app development would i also have to learn winRT api or would i use the same .net framework classes that i use to develop winform or WPF app.

Comment: It depends if the .NET classes you want to use are supported. Windows 8 introduces a new native runtime called Windows Runtime (WinRT), which is the backbone of the new Metro user experience in Windows 8. You should try to only use WinRT if you start from scratch. If you need to use old .NET classes you have to check for compatibility and recompile them under WinRT or use the Portable Class Library (PLC) approach. Look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10807123/does-net-4-0-business-apis-work-with-win-8-metro-apps

Comment: So in essence either i can develop in winforms, WPF using .NET framework classes. Or i can develop in Metro using the partially supported .NET framework classes for winRT. Right ?

Comment: For a complete explanation of the future of .NET and WinRT and the possibility to use them together please look here http://www.lhotka.net/weblog/WinRTAndNET.aspx

Comment: @SomeBody There are some companies that specialize in creating legacy compatibility layers for some of the old .NET APIs for Windows 8 Metro interface, like this one: http://www.moderncomponents.com/, so you may ask them if they can or plan to support any of the APIs you need.